# Regex to split on new lines with a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a string into multiple strings (like observations).

For example, a sample text with 3 "bidder id" observations is:

```
       BID RANK       BID TOTAL   BIDDER ID         BIDDER INFORMATION  (NAME/ADDRESS/LOCATION)
       --------      -----------  ---------         -------------------------------------------------
           1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00814766
                                                    P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                    COLTON CA  92324

           2         1,534,243.00    3              EXCEL PAVING COMPANY                  562 599-5841  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00688659
                                                    2230 LEMON AVENUE                 FAX 562 591-7485
                                                    LONG BEACH CA  90806

           3         1,593,549.40    2              SECURITY PAVING COMPANY INC           818 767-8418  CC PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00116307
                                                    P O BOX 1489                      FAX 818 767-3169
                                                    SUN VALLEY CA  91353-1489
```

The ultimate goal is to create a dataset that mimics this text document. The first step is to split this big string into multiple small strings. For example, the three small strings would look as follows:

**Split string 1**

```
           1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00814766
                                                    P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                    COLTON CA  92324
```

**Split string 2**

```
           2         1,534,243.00    3              EXCEL PAVING COMPANY                  562 599-5841  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00688659
                                                    2230 LEMON AVENUE                 FAX 562 591-7485
                                                    LONG BEACH CA  90806
```

**Split String 3**

```
           3         1,593,549.40    2              SECURITY PAVING COMPANY INC           818 767-8418  CC PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00116307
                                                    P O BOX 1489                      FAX 818 767-3169
                                                    SUN VALLEY CA  91353-1489
```

I started using the split pattern as `[\r\n]+\s+`, but unfortunately, it splits by any new line and not just the new line with no other character/text in it.

Code:

```
# imports
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import docx2txt
import textract
import antiword

txt = "                   1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                              00814766
                                                        P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                        COLTON CA  92324

               2         1,534,243.00    3              EXCEL PAVING COMPANY                  562 599-5841  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                              00688659
                                                        2230 LEMON AVENUE                 FAX 562 591-7485
                                                        LONG BEACH CA  90806

               3         1,593,549.40    2              SECURITY PAVING COMPANY INC           818 767-8418  CC PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                              00116307
                                                        P O BOX 1489                      FAX 818 767-3169
                                                        SUN VALLEY CA  91353-1489"

p = re.split("[\r\n]+",txt)
```

But it splits text by all the possible new lines. Is there a way to separate text by a *newline* with no other character in it? Thank you so much!!

P.S. if you think I'm doing something wildly wrong or if there's a much simpler way to create a dataset - please let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: A line with no characters in it: `^$`. A line with maybe whitespace in it: `^\s*$`.

Comment: @Friedrich - thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't split the text the way we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `re.findall` with pattern ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nBFYAY/1)):

```
(?ms)^\s{,20}\d.*?(?=^\s{,20}\d|\Z)
```

---

```py
import re

text = """\
       BID RANK       BID TOTAL   BIDDER ID         BIDDER INFORMATION  (NAME/ADDRESS/LOCATION)
       --------      -----------  ---------         -------------------------------------------------
           1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00814766
                                                    P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                    COLTON CA  92324

           2         1,534,243.00    3              EXCEL PAVING COMPANY                  562 599-5841  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00688659
                                                    2230 LEMON AVENUE                 FAX 562 591-7485
                                                    LONG BEACH CA  90806

           3         1,593,549.40    2              SECURITY PAVING COMPANY INC           818 767-8418  CC PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00116307
                                                    P O BOX 1489                      FAX 818 767-3169
                                                    SUN VALLEY CA  91353-1489"""

groups = re.findall(r"(?ms)^\s{,20}\d.*?(?=^\s{,20}\d|\Z)", text)

for group in groups:
    print(group)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
           1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00814766
                                                    P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                    COLTON CA  92324

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           2         1,534,243.00    3              EXCEL PAVING COMPANY                  562 599-5841  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00688659
                                                    2230 LEMON AVENUE                 FAX 562 591-7485
                                                    LONG BEACH CA  90806

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           3         1,593,549.40    2              SECURITY PAVING COMPANY INC           818 767-8418  CC PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                          00116307
                                                    P O BOX 1489                      FAX 818 767-3169
                                                    SUN VALLEY CA  91353-1489
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture those blocks with:

```
(?=^[ \t]+(?:\d+[ \t]+[\d,.]+[ \t]+\d))([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:^[ \t]+\d+[ \t]+[\d,.]+[ \t]+\d)|\Z)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F4TJ3O/1)

Or split like this and deal with the header by poping 2 lines off before the split:

```
re.split(r'(?:\r?\n){2}, s)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jjrq5b/1)

Python demo:

```
s='''\
BID RANK       BID TOTAL   BIDDER ID         BIDDER INFORMATION  (NAME/ADDRESS/LOCATION)
--------      -----------  ---------         -------------------------------------------------
        1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                                                                                                    00814766
                                                                                        P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                                                        COLTON CA  92324

        2         1,534,243.00    3              EXCEL PAVING COMPANY                  562 599-5841  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                                                                                                    00688659
                                                                                        2230 LEMON AVENUE                 FAX 562 591-7485
                                                                                        LONG BEACH CA  90806

        3         1,593,549.40    2              SECURITY PAVING COMPANY INC           818 767-8418  CC PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                                                                                                    00116307
                                                                                        P O BOX 1489                      FAX 818 767-3169
                                                                                        SUN VALLEY CA  91353-1489'''

import re 

# with re.split:
print(
    "\n-------\n".join(re.split(r'(?:\r?\n){2,}', "\n".join(s.splitlines()[2:])))
)

# with re.findall:

print(
    "\n-------\n".join(re.findall(r'(?=^[ \t]+(?:\d+[ \t]+[\d,.]+[ \t]))([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:^[ \t]+\d+[ \t]+[\d,.]+[ \t])|\Z)', s, flags=re.M))
)
```

Both methods prints:

```
        1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                                                                                                    00814766
                                                                                        P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                                                        COLTON CA  92324
-------
        2         1,534,243.00    3              EXCEL PAVING COMPANY                  562 599-5841  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                                                                                                    00688659
                                                                                        2230 LEMON AVENUE                 FAX 562 591-7485
                                                                                        LONG BEACH CA  90806
-------
        3         1,593,549.40    2              SECURITY PAVING COMPANY INC           818 767-8418  CC PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                                                                                                    00116307
                                                                                        P O BOX 1489                      FAX 818 767-3169
                                                                                        SUN VALLEY CA  91353-1489
```